# How can i use interop excel on c++

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm having a big problem porting C# code to C++ code. I'm trying to save all my `datagridview` info into an Excel file but it's giving me a lot of errors. These are my 2 headers and I already added the interop dll. I'm just having problems cause I've found a lot of C# info but not C++ and I'm still a student.

```
using namespace Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel;

#define Excel   Microsoft::Office::Interop::Excel
```

// Here is the button:

```
Excel::Application^ xlApp =gcnew Excel::ApplicationClass();
Excel::Workbook^ xlWorkBook=xlApp->Workbooks->Add(Type::Missing); 
Excel::Worksheet xlWorkSheet =(Excel::Worksheet)xlWorkBook::Worksheets->get_Item(1); 
object misValue = System->Reflection->Missing->Value;

int i = 0;
int j = 0; 

for (i = 0; i <= DGV_ComprasUsuarios->RowCount  - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= DGV_ComprasUsuarios->ColumnCount  - 1; j++)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = DGV_ComprasUsuarios[j, i];
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell->Value;
    }
}

xlWorkBook::SaveAs("csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook::Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp::Quit();

releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);

MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls");
```

Comment: The reason you don't find much info is that, if you must program to .Net, most people use VB.Net or C#.  C/C++ is great for Win32 or Linux.  But the dialect of C++ you need for .Net - [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) - isn't really "C++" ... and isn't terribly popular.  You're probably much better off ifyou can just use VB.Net or C#.  IMHO...

Comment: Yeah i know that, but its just for a simple code. I mean parsing some int values to an excel. Its an add for my final project. Is it too hard?

Comment: You forgot to post what problem you are getting. Can you post a [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions/22762#22762)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I tested working. The only thing I noticed is that the values are rounded after 6, 7, or 8 digits after the decimal point. It should not be a big deal.

```
   System::Void yourForm::saveAttenuDataGridViewCalValues(
                 System::Windows::Forms::DataGridView^ DataGridView1)
     {
         Excel::Application^ xlApp = nullptr ;
         Excel::Workbook^ xlWorkBook = nullptr;
         Excel::Worksheet^ xlWorkSheet = nullptr;
         Object^ misValue = System::Reflection::Missing::Value;

         xlApp = gcnew Excel::ApplicationClass();
         xlWorkBook = xlApp->Workbooks->Add(misValue);
         xlWorkSheet = static_cast<Excel::Worksheet^>(xlWorkBook->Worksheets->Item[1]);
         int i = 0;
         int j = 0; 

         for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1->RowCount  - 1; i++)
         {
             for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1->ColumnCount  - 1; j++)
             {
                 DataGridViewCell^ cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                 xlWorkSheet->Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell->Value;
             }
          }

          xlWorkBook->SaveAs("cppCli.net-informations.xls", Excel::XlFileFormat::xlWorkbookNormal, 
                             misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,           
                             Excel::XlSaveAsAccessMode::xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, 
                             misValue, misValue);
          xlWorkBook->Close(true, misValue, misValue);
          xlApp->Quit();


           MessageBox::ShowMessage("Excel file created , you can find the file cppCli.net-
                                   informations.xls", false);
       }
```